# Error when update ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade ubuntu 19.04 to 20.20 but have an error like this:

```
update-manager     
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py:23: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit.py:33: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as WebKit
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 was intended to upgrade to the next release, ie. 19.10.  To skip releases, the easiest method is a re-install, selecting your existing partitions, and ensuring you don't format (no user files are touched, only system directories are wiped, thus certain server type applications may require config files to be restore manually; this won't impact desktop files).  Use a LTS release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.

Comment: It's not my question, it has 427 upvotes

Comment: My guess is you've already been given this, but https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error.

That's the expected behavior when you miss the release-upgrade window. You are several months too late for a release-upgrade.

- Your remaining supported release-upgrade method is to backup your data and clean-install a supported release of Ubuntu.
- There are several unsupported methods you could try...but if you run into problems we won't offer useful help. They are not supported.
- Consider marking your calendar so you don't miss the three-month-long release-upgrade windows (October-January and April-July). Or consider migrating to an LTS so release upgrades happen every two years.